# How do I wait to execute my code until all of my images are loaded in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

my code is

```
  var stone = new Image(20, 20);

  var grass = new Image(20, 20);

  var dirt = new Image(20, 20);
  
  stone.id = 'stone' ;
  stone.src = 'stone.png';  
  dirt.src = 'dirt.png';
  dirt.id = 'dirt' 
  grass.src = 'grass.png'; 
  grass.id = 'grass'`
```

and I want to make it so the rest of my code will run after all these images have loaded because as it is now, the images dont get loaded in and when I use them in the HTML Canvas they don't show up

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try anything?

Comment: I have tried several things and keep getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading images before rendering JS canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336830/loading-images-before-rendering-js-canvas)

Comment: See also [Images onload in one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527416/images-onload-in-one-function/58529126#58529126)